# Merge Conflicts and Poor UI with .Net Resource Strings

Tags: c#, .net, mercurial

Resource strings are quite irritating.

1. You have to copy the text into Notepad++ to edit them
2. Scrolling through large strings is near impossible
3. When you press F12 on a resource string reference, it brings you to the proxy to the resource store, but no way to edit, nor can you see the full text of long strings.
4. As more developers fill the list of resource strings, merge conflicts occur more and more on the XML resource files.

Is there a way to stop merge conflicts in the XML resource string files? Is there a better way?

Comment: Please comment the reason if you downvote

Comment: Seriously, someone took the time to downvote my question, I get no constructive feedback, just a sucker punch to my reputation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You have to copy the text into Notepad++ to edit them

Visual Studio also provides an XML editor view for resource files. I use this almost exclusively over datasheet view.  Give it a try.

> Scrolling through large strings is near impossible

Probably easier in XML view.

> When you press F12 on a resource string reference, it brings you to the proxy to the resource store, but no way to edit, nor can you see the full text of long strings.

I just use ctrl+F and type in the resource ID.

> As more developers fill the list of resource strings, merge conflicts occur more and more on the XML resource files.

Merge problems are greatly reduced if all developers ensure that resources are added or inserted to the file in alphabetical order. We wrote a script to do it and put it into the automated build.

Also, consider organizing your resources into separate files for different purposes, e.g. control labels can go in one file and large text sections can go in a different file.  This will reduce contention as well.

Comment: Wow, there's a lot of new things in here for me to consider thanks!

Comment: 1. Can you have separate resource files? (It would seem so). 2. How does alphabetical sorting of resources minimize merge contentions (it's not obvious to me)

Comment: 1. Yes   2. When developers insert stuff in any order they want, TFS has a tough time figuring out how to automatically merge their changes.  It's especially bad when a developer decides to *move* a resource from one spot to another-- the merge tool might thing a whole portion of the file has moved.  That all goes away when you put everything in a deterministic order (it doesn't have to be alphabetical, but most people know that one).

Comment: ew, TFS. Although I like my own answer better, I'll award this as the answer, because it's a great option if you want to keep using Resource strings (which could be a hard sell with rusted on software engineers). Hopefully, others will find my own answer useful, and by 2040 it will be the standard for AI coders.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is - code.

Create a separate static class, I like to suffix "Queries" if it's full of SQL, or "Resources" if it's more general.

In C#, you can use @"", that's enough, but the more recent $@"" is nice if you want to interpolate.

Example:

```
public class ApplicationStructureCacheQueries
{
    public static readonly string ChangeOverNew = $@"
    delete from ApplicationStructureCache
    insert into ApplicationStructureCache
    select * from #NewApplicationStructureCache
    ";
}
```

Code Control works very well with line-based coding languages (rather than structured data with multi-line associations - XML). You get the full power of your coding language to work with your strings, including inheritance if you need to (but make it a singleton object, instead of static reference), or perhaps an interpolating function, so it's nice and typesafe and cohesive.